# My projection coordinate system does not show right figures on my print layout axes

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using QGIS 3.10.2 and trying to figure out why my coordinate system, although it shows right Lat/long figures on basic working screen(see 1st photo), when I try to work on **Print Layout** gives me wrong Lat/Long values. Small island on map(red circle) should be 16'5739.55 43'96496.18 under Greekgrid GGRS87 EPSG:2100 or 22.38181.886268 48.16018.276529 under EPSG:3857 WGS84 instead it shows 10'00 N and 16'E. All project layers are setup to EPSG:2100. All WMS layers are correctly aligned with my project.Project CRS is set to EPSG:2100. Appearence CRS is set to EPSG:2100. In PrintLayout Map/main propereties/grid is also set to EPSG:2100.

[image: small island]

[image: main screen]

[image: project crs]

Comment: So, you're printing the grid in 5 cm intervals and wonder why it is printed in 5 cm intervals?

Comment: What ever interval I choose has the same effect. Only when I change to NATO EPSG 4326 I get the right degrees. I think it is because EPSG:2100 unit is in meters while EPSG 4326 in degrees. 1/50 and 1/100 has the right effect.